# Axis automatically changed?

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot, where the lines are only in the negative range and when I plot it, the axis is automatically changed, i.e. negative larger values are going up and not down, in a normal plot. Currently I have the following plot:

[image: te]

But I want to have the y axis the other way round, so that negative larger values are going down and not up, I hope it is understandable what I mean.

How can I achieve this in R?

My code with my specific data is just using the normal plot() function.

Comment: it's a bit hard to believe this comes from the default R `plot` command.  Are you using a specific package (which may define a `plot` method for a particular class of input that flips the axis)? Can you give us a reproducible example, please?  If I `plot(1:100,rnorm(100))` I get the y-axis oriented normally ...

Comment: @BenBolker but your rnorm(100) values: There are also some positive values, in my case there are only negative values. R changed this automatically, I just used the normal plot() function.

Comment: I'm still having trouble believing you got this from default `plot`. `plot(1:100,-abs(rnorm(100)))` (with only negative y values) gives me the expected plot.  Does it 'flip' for you?  If so, what are the results of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @BenBolker Okay I know where the problem is: I want to have a specific range in the negative area, so I also set a ylim=c(-0.05,-1) and then this happens?

Comment: The axis labelling and dotted guide lines tells me this is no ordinary plot. What is the class of the thing you are plotting?

Comment: @Spacedman the dotted lines are just added with grid()

Comment: so set `ylim=c(-1,-0.05)` (!!)  I have to say this is not **automatically** flipping -- R did what you asked it to ...

Comment: @BenBolker nice! It works, thanks! So easy :-)

Comment: This is why you should give minimal examples that show the problem!

Comment: Please go ahead and answer your own question below ...

Answer (score 2):

As Ben Bolker said, the following has to be said:
I set the ylim range wrong, I set it like

> ylim=c(-0.05,-1)

but

> ylim=c(-1,-0.05)

should do what I want!